# Why did Debian 8 Jessie install the GNU bootloader onto my computer?

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I recently installed Debian 8 Jessie onto a USB stick, but even without the USB stick inserted I get a prompt from the GNU bootloader every time I start my computer.

I find this highly unusual as I never specified any portion of the installation process to overwrite/change any part of the drives on my computer itself, only the USB stick.

Has anyone else experienced this, and what exactly might I do about it considering the fact that I have 0 experience with bootloaders or MBRs, and specifically wanted to avoid messing with something that can permanently ruin my computer if I make a mistake?

Comment: It seems that you installed the bootloader in the hard disk instead of the USB stick. AFAIK Debian 8 doesn't overwrite your HD boot sector unless you instruct it to do so. What exact steps have you you followed to make the installation?

Comment: I recommend the installer expert mode when doing anything outside the usual.  It gives you more control over what and where.

Comment: Clearly note that booting from a Debian USB installation **does not** install a boot loader on your computer.  That **must** have been done by a command you gave it.

Comment: If this is really reproducible and **not** caused by user error, please raise a [bug](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I find this highly unusual as I never specified any portion of the installation process to overwrite/change any part of the drives on my computer itself, only the USB stick.

Traditionally (I haven't run the Debian installer recently), there is a question the installer asks about installing GRUB to the MBR. This question is completely separate from the selection of destination partitions for installing Debian to. If you say "yes", it will write to your main drive's MBR, even if you are installing to a USB drive (which has its own MBR).

> Has anyone else experienced this, and what exactly might I do about it considering the fact that I have 0 experience with bootloaders or MBRs, and specifically wanted to avoid messing with something that can permanently ruin my computer if I make a mistake?

Well, if you're not willing to mess with it, you won't be able to fix it. You just need to boot into Windows and restore the MBR. See, e.g., https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/ for a guide on how to do this.